# Need an update query to update score from reference table to target table based on the columns of target table

Tags: mysql, database

[image]

I would like to update score from reference table to target table based on the id and batch id columns. So 101 should be updated 7 rows for batch 119. Please refer the image for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 t11
  JOIN table1 t12 ON t11.batchid = t12.batchid
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t12.id = t2.id
SET t11.score = t2.score
```

Comment: Thanks for your query. I ran it but its taking lot of time to update the records. Is there any way to make the query faster bcz i have more than 50k batches to update

Comment: @Sai Create indices - they will help.

Comment: even when i added index batchid and unique key on t2.id..its taking lot of time

Comment: is there a way to optimize the query

Comment: @Sai The only way to optimize is to create proper indices. I do not see another way for optimization. On your real data array try to create composite indices `table1 (batchid, id)` and `table1 (id, batchid)` and check EXPLAIN - maybe one of them will be used (primarily the first - instead of separate index by (batchid)).